# I can echo all my data on my website, but I can't put all of it in my html

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so this is my code:

```
require_once"database.php";
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reserveringen");

if($result->num_rows != 0) {

    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Email = $rows["Email"];
        $Tijd = $rows["Tijd"];

    }

}
```

I want to get all of the rows from my table called "reserveringen" and place it inside my html. When I type `echo("$Email $Tijd")` it gives me all the Emailaddresses and Tijd that I need. But when I type `$message = "$Email $Tijd";` and put the $message in my html it only gives me 1 Email and 1 Tijd. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
<?php if($message) { ?>
        <p><?= $message; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please show us how you are printing `$message`, i have the suspicion that you assign `$message` and then print it after the loop has ended, so only the last element is in the variable

Comment: @Rizier123 It's in the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i though you assign `$message` in the while loop and overwrite it each iteration, so at the end the last element is stored in the variable.

If you then print it outside of the loop only the last element get's printed.

So what you could do is, make `$message` a array and print it with a loop like this:

```
$message = array();   
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Email = $rows["Email"];
    $Tijd = $rows["Tijd"];
    $message[] = "$Email $Tijd";
}
```

And then you can print it like this:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($message)) { 
        foreach($message as $value) {
?>
    <p><?= $value; ?></p>
<?php 
        } //end foreach
    } //end if

?>
```

(Or if you want you can output the values directly in the while loop)

Comment: And once again, you saved me! Thank you Rizier123!:)